# Using Gravity Forms "gform_after_submission" filter hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to update the post and edit the value of an existing field with a sequence number after the entry has been created at `gform_after_submission` hook.

The requirement is to update a single field value in the same post and then update the post. I I found [this documentation](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_after_submission) but not that helpful.

And tried the following but it's updating all the fields:

```
add_filter( "gform_save_field_value", "set_field_value", 10, 4 ); 

function set_field_value( $value, $lead, $field, $form ){ 
    if( $form['id'] != 1 || $field['id'] != 19 ) 
        return; 

    $value = "xxx"; 
    return $value; 
}
```

Comment: I found the following link but not that helpful: [gravityhelp.com](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_after_submission)

Comment: I tried the following but its updating all the fields  `add_filter("gform_save_field_value", "set_field_value", 10, 4);
 function set_field_value($value, $lead, $field, $form){
  if($form['id'] != 1 || $field['id'] != 19)
   return;
 $value = "xxx";
 return $value;
}`

Comment: I've already edited it, but please, add this kind of information to the Question itself. +1 for bringing up research efforts and showing what you have tried. ::: Small correction: a filter should always return a value, so you need the first one to be `return $value;` too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the issue using the below code:

```
add_filter("gform_get_input_value", "update_field", 10, 4);

    function update_field($value, $lead, $field, $input_id){
        if($lead["form_id"] == 1 && $field["id"] == 19)
            return 'xxx';
        else
            return $value;
    }

    add_filter("gform_save_field_value", "save_field_value", 10, 4);

    function save_field_value($value, $lead, $field, $form){
        if($lead["form_id"] == 1 && $field["id"] == 19)
            return 'xxx';
        else
            return $value;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your logic is a bit off I would check IF it IS the right field rather than if it's not and do something like this:

```
    add_filter( "gform_save_field_value", "nifty_set_field_value", 10, 4 ); 

    function nifty_set_field_value( $value, $lead, $field, $form ){ 
    //make sure we are on form 1 AND field 19
    if( $form['id'] == 1 &&  $field['id'] == 19 ){
        //set value
        $value = "xxx";
        //return
        return $value; 
    } 
   //not our field, that's okay just return the normal value
   else {return $value;  }
```

You may be able to do it without the `else` and just return value once but if I remember right (and the docs show) both are needed.

Or you could do it with your current code:

```
    add_filter( "gform_save_field_value", "nifty_set_field_value", 10, 4 ); 

function nifty_set_field_value( $value, $lead, $field, $form ){ 
    if( $form['id'] != 1 || $field['id'] != 19 ) {
        return $value; 
}
$value = "xxx"; 
return $value;
```

}

just make sure you return the value not just return the function

Here is a link to [the correct docs page](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_save_field_value) Also Gravity Forms has a [support form](http://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/) of its own for users who have paid for the product. Lastly, Check out their [example pastie](http://pastie.org/1469933)

Comment: how can I wrap this filter under the `gform_after_submission` so that it can be called on event